# What is the best probability of recurrent stillbirth with the given data

Tags: miscarriage, 3rd-trimester, birth-defect

**Summary**: My son was stillborn and I don't know why. My wife and I would like to have another child, but would very much not like to try if the probability of this occurring again is above a certain threshold (of which we have already settled on one). All 3 doctors I have consulted were unable to give a definitive cause of death, nor were any willing to give a numerical estimate of the probability (whether for reasons of legal risk, or something else) that our next baby will be stillborn. I am likely too distraught to properly evaluate my situation and would very much appreciate an independent (from mine) probability estimate of what caused my son to die, and given that cause, how likely it is that our next child will die as well.

**Background**: V (L and my only biologically related living son) had no complications during birth, nor has he showed any signs of poor health whatsoever. L has a cousin who has had two miscarriages, and I have an aunt who had several stillbirths followed by 3 live births of healthy children. We know of no other family members that have had similar misfortunes.

J (my deceased son) was the product of a 31 week gestation. L (my wife and J's mother) is 28 years old, gravida 2, para 1. L presented to the physicians office for routine prenatal care and noted that she had not felt any fetal movement for the last five to six days. No fetal heart tones were identified. It was determined that there was an intrauterine fetal demise. L was admitted on 11/05/2015 for induction and was delivered of a nonviable, normal appearing, male fetus at approximately 1:30 on 11/06/2015.

**Pro-Con Reasoning**: According to a leading obstetrics textbook1, causes of stillbirth are commonly classified into 8 categories: obstetrical complications, placental abnormalities, fetal malformations, infection, umbilical cord abnormalities, hypertensive disorders, medical complications, and undetermined. Below, I'll list the percentage of stillbirths in each category (which may be used as prior probabilities) along with some reasons for or against.

*Obstetrical complications* (29%)

> Against: No abruption detected. No multifetal gestation. No ruptured
>   preterm membranes at 20-24 weeks.

*Placental abnormalities* (24%)

> For: Excessive fibrin deposition (as concluded in the surgical
>   pathology report). Early acute chorioamnionitis (as conclused in the
>   surgical pathology report, but Dr. M claimed this was caused by the
>   baby's death, not conversely). L has gene variants associated with
>   deep vein thrombosis (AG on rs2227589 per 23andme raw data).
>
> Against: No factor V Leiden mutation (GG on rs6025 per 23andme raw
>   data and confirmed via independent lab test). No prothrombin gene
>   mutation (GG on l3002432 per 23andme raw data and confirmed via
>   independent lab test). L was negative for prothrombin G20210A mutation
>   (as determined by lab test). Anti-thrombin III activity results were
>   within normal reference ranges (as determined by lab test). Protein C
>   activity results were withing normal reference ranges (as determined
>   by lab test). Protein S activity results were within normal reference
>   ranges (as determined by lab test). Protein S antigen (free and total)
>   results were within normal references ranges (as determined by lab
>   test).

*Infection* (13%)

> For: L visited a nurse's home during the last week of August that
>   works in a hospital we now know had frequent cases of CMV infection.
>   CMV antibody IgH, CMV IgG, and Parvovirus B-19 Antibody IgG values
>   were outside of normal reference ranges.
>
> Against: Dr. M discounted the viral test results as the cause of
>   death, since the levels suggested the infection had occurred years
>   ago, and therefore could not have caused J's death. Dr. F confirmed
>   Dr. M's assessment.

*Fetal malformations* (14%)

> Against: No major structural abnormalities. No genetic abnormalities
>   detected (CombiSNP Array for Pregnancy Loss results showed a normal
>   male micro array profile).

*Umbilical cord abnormalities* (10%)

> Against: No prolapse. No stricture. No thrombosis.

*Hypertensive disorder* (9%)

> Against: No preeclampsia. No chronic hypertension.

*Medical complications* (8%)

> For: L experienced 2 nights of very painful abdominal pains that could
>   have been contractions on 10/28 and 10/29. L remembers waking up on
>   her back a few nights between 10/20 and 11/05 (it is unclear if this
>   belongs in this category or somewhere else).
>
> Against: No antiphospholipid antibody syndrome detected (determined
>   via Beta-2 Glycoprotein I Antibodies [IgG, IgA, IgM] test). No
>   maternal diabetes detected (determined via glucose test on 10/20).

*Undetermined* (24%)

What is the most likely cause of death? How likely is that cause? Given that cause, if we choose to have another child, then how likely is it to survive its birth? Are there any other ways I could reduce uncertainty (additional tests, etc...) that I haven't listed here? Are there any other forums where these questions are more likely to get good answers? Why won't doctors give probabilities? Help with any of these questions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

If your advice to me is to consult another expert (in addition to the 2 obstetricians and 1 high-risk obstetrician I already have consulted), please also provide concrete tactics as to how to find such an expert and validate their expertise.

Comment: Ma'am, I have mathematical background but very brief knowledge about human biology. I'll ask my sister, she's a great doctor at a well reputed hospital. She'll be able to help. Also, my sincere sympathy with you, i can understand the importance of this question.

Comment: I'm a sir, but I would very much appreciate any help you could give. Thank you.

Comment: I am so very sorry for your loss. I have one question and some advice. My question concerns your ancestry. Do you happen to have any Ashkenazi Jewish heritage? The advice is, you won't get an answer with anything even close to the precision you want on this site. It's a new site and there are no geneticists, perinatologists, or even obstretricians here. The doctors you've dealt with (if you've not consulted a geneticist, I'd advise you to do so if the heritage is there) are going to be your best advisers. Again, you have my sympathy.

Comment: My deepest sympathies as well. anongoodnurse is correct, anything we could provide would be a guess at best, and you deserve much more than that. Please, see some specialists that have experience in this area and can conduct the appropriate testings for you. Unfortunately, since this is would be a lot of guesswork on our part and very much personal medical advice, I will need to close this as an off topic question.

Comment: Looks like my question was put on hold, and I am advised that 'Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records'. This reason rings hollow, since I have already done so, and all of the specialists (perhaps because of legal risk) were unwilling to give me a numerical probability estimate, which is what my question is about. A 'guess' by someone who knows more statistics or medicine than I do would be so much more helpful than no estimate at all.

Comment: @sh1 Yes, even something with a very small prior probability can happen. I know this all too well. In fact, it did happen when my son died. Might this be a coping strategy? I don't really know, but I fail to see how wanting to base one's actions on combination of probability and utility rather than simply the utility is in any way unreasonable. What I do know, is that there are certain risks that are not worth taking and others that are. For instance, if the risk was 4%, I wouldn't hesitate to try again, but if it was 40%, I certainly would not.

Comment: I am a physician and I agree with the comment directly above this one. It is not from fear of legal ramifications that your doctors are silent; it is because you're asking them to predict the future. No one can do that in your case.

Comment: There are just too many variables for anyone to give a hard percentage range. As @anongoodnurse pointed out a geneticist would be a worth while pursuit. Instead of preeclampsia was HELLP w/o preeclampsia symptoms considered? How about other infections? Are you in a location where your food or water supply may be suspect (local well water for example)? Most txt written for US medical practice won't focus on those issues as they are far less common in the US than developing countries.